# Is it possible to have consecutive or operators in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Currently I have

```
if [[ $INPUT_FILE == *".aac" ]] || [[ $INPUT_FILE == *".aiff" ]] || [[ $INPUT_FILE == *".pcm" ]]
```

I have tried the following, which does not work. It does not match anything.

```
if [[ $INPUT_FILE == *".aac" || *".aiff" || *".pcm" ]]
```

Is there any way to factor this expression?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet well I mean it doesn't work. I was just trying to give the idea of what i was looking for

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thanks for the recommendation! will do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `[[` you could use a regex (specifically, an Extended Regular Expression)

```
if [[ $input_file =~ \.(aac|aiff|pcm)$ ]]; then
  : something
fi
```

or an extglob

```
if [[ $input_file = *.@(aac|aiff|pcm) ]]; then
  : something
fi
```

Or you may use a `case` statement

```
case $input_file in
 *.aac | *.aiff | *.pcm )
   # anything
 ;;
esac
```

Comment: "extglob" patterns are documented in [3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)